# Изменение размера картинки с последующим скачиванием

Tags: php, javascript

Как реализовать скачивание картинки с сервера с изменением ее разрешения. Есть селект с выбором разрешения кнопка скачать ну и сама картинка

Comment: в чем проблема то ваша?

Comment: Я не знаю как это сделать, с чего начать

Comment: начните со скачивания картинки без изменения её разрешения. А потом - меняйте разрешение в зависимости от выбранных пользователем параметров.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте форму вида:

```
<form action="somescript.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select>
        <option value="800x600">800x600</option>
    </select>
    <input type="file" name="image">
</form>
```

в somescript.php подключите какую-нибудь библиотеку для ресайза изображений, например [эту](https://github.com/eventviva/php-image-resize), она неплохо описана

Откройте в ней загруженный файл, с учетом его размеров и **соотношения сторон** измените размер. 
После этого выведите в браузер методом `$image->output()`.

Для того чтобы **сохранить изображение** необходим дополнительный заголовок
`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $output_filename . '"');`

Для нарезки изображений вам необходим [модуль GD](http://php.net/image). Чаще всего он подключен по-умолчанию.

Comment: Подскажите, а если брать вот этот http://sanchiz.net/blog/resizing-images-with-php  Как реализовать скачивание результата  Получаю вывод изображения с измененным разрешением     header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');   $image = new SimpleImage();   $image->load('2.jpg');   $image->resizeToWidth(650);   $image->output();      Пробую сохранить, но не чего не происходит     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $image->output() . '"');

Comment: Все заголовки должны быть отправлены до вызова метода `$image->output()`